# Find picture url

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

I am developing in shopify and want to add the `background` `image` below but can't find the url link for it. I know you can find it in `Settings -> Files`. But I need the actual `picture url online` to then upload it.

[image: Image I want to get]

Comment: You can find image URL from Settings -> Files from Admin panel

Comment: @DeepakNirala yes I know how to find the image within shopify. I am trying to find the background image online

Comment: I don't believe that we can help you here. StackOverflow is a platform for helping developers with their coding issues. This is clearly not a coding issue. Please consult the Shopify support or theme support if you can't find a specific setting or location.

Answer (score 1):

This section is being controlled from theme customization.

Go into customize theme, sections and there you will see option to change backgroud image.